# Git: How can I remove conflict changes during merge into master

Tags: git

I have the following problem:

I have three developers working on branch 'develop',
dev2 made huge mistakes and it produced lots of conflicts.
I want to merge only the 'safe' contributions from dev1 and dev3 into master branch and remove all dev2 contributions, keeping 'develop' branch clan also. How can I do that? It's a theoretical problem, I have only a diagram to show here:

[image: here the diagram]

Thanks to all.

Comment: You might consider creating another branch off master and cherry picking the "good" commits onto that branch. `git cherry-pick somecommithash`

Comment: Merge conflicts are not "mistakes" or "unsafe".

Comment: Mistakes and conflicts aren’t the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command on your develop branch:

`git rebase -i <commit_to_remove>~1`

An editor will start up listing all of the commits after commit_to_remove. If you delete the line containing the commit you want to delate and save the file, then rebase does the rest.

Comment: what's the `-i` flag?

Comment: interactive mode